# Rebol3 - How do you extract all the GUI styles with descriptions in Rebol3 after load-gui is evaluated?

Tags: rebol, rebol3, r3-gui

(edited per suggestions)

How do you extract all the GUI styles with descriptions in Rebol3 after load-gui is evaluated?

Comment: It should be possible, with a small script, to auto-generate a nice document that describes all of the GUI styles, and even generate a nice HTML summary page.

Comment: Not sure I have the PARSE ability to do that, but it sounds great, Carl

Comment: @kealist this ought to be a start: `load-gui
do http://reb4.me/r3/rsp
style-info: collect [foreach [name style] body-of guie/styles [keep form name keep style/about]]
render-each [name about] style-info {<h1><%== name %></h1>^/<p><%== about %></p>^/}`

Comment: @rgchris Thank you, I'll play around with that to get it.  I need to prepare some r3 documents for other thick-headed people like myself to learn how to do GUI stuff

Comment: How about rewording your question to reflect the answer Chris provided ...ie. how do you extract all the GUI styles with descriptions in Rebol3 after load-gui is evaluated?

Comment: @GrahamChiu Done, but I guess it was already closed.

Comment: Nope, it has been opened again :)

Comment: I posted a comment to the admin who closed it and he removed the comment and opened it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from @rgchris, an initial idea:

```
REBOL []
load-gui 
do http://reb4.me/r3/rsp 

style-info: collect [
    foreach [name style] body-of guie/styles [
        keep form name keep style/about
    ]
] 

styles-list: render-each [name about] style-info {<h1><%== name %></h1>^/<p><%== about %></p>^/}

write %styles-list.html styles-list
```